# Is it possible to start an app as admin in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to create a scheduled task that runs an app as an admin. Is this possible?

My current task action is this

```
powershell 
$packageFamilyName = (Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'MyApp' } 
  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PackageFamilyName);    
Start-Process shell:appsFolder\$packageFamilyName!MyApp;
```

Comment: Use the Task Scheduler settings.  Under the General Tab, enable the setting for highest elevation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the
[Start-Process command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-7.1):

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -FilePath "notepad" -ArgumentList arguments
```

For more discussion and other possibilities, see
[Running a command as Administrator using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/running-a-command-as-administrator-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `RunAs` PowerShell cmdlet.

e.g. `runas /user:admin powershell`

where admin is the name of your administrator account.

Comment: I think `runas` is a windows command - not a powershell cmdlet.